# store voice file path android xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, storage, attachment

the following code is what I use to grab a voice file to send an email as an attachment. However, I am not able to find this file. no clue where it is stored. (this is what I see when I hover the path ***/storage/emulated/0/test.mp4***). the storage folder is empty even when this run, for this reason, the attachment can't be sent. any ideas? Thank you! *updated code*

```
string path = "";

    public Recorder_Droid()
    {
        var sqlliteFilname = "test.mp4";


        string filePath = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        path = Path.Combine(filePath, sqlliteFilname);



        _recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        _player = new MediaPlayer();

        _player.Completion += (sender, e) => {
            _player.Reset();
        };
    }

    MediaRecorder _recorder;
    MediaPlayer _player;

    public void PlayAudio()
    {

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }

        if (_recorder == null)
        {
            _recorder = new MediaRecorder();

        }

        _recorder.Reset();
        _recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
        _recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);
        _recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Aac); 
        _recorder.SetOutputFile(path); 


        _recorder.Prepare(); // Prepared state
        _recorder.Start(); // Recording state.
        return;
```

Comment: How are you creating the file `test.3gpp`?

Comment: What is a 3gpp file?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply . I updated the code @SushiHangover